# How to turn a visual selection into a visual block selection?

Tags: vim

Is there an easy way to use a visual selection, made with `vip` for example, and turn it into a visual block selection?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is under `:help visual-mode`, which even has this handy "table":

```
          new mode after typing:
old mode            "v"       "CTRL-V"            "V"

Normal              Visual    blockwise Visual    linewise Visual
Visual              Normal    blockwise Visual    linewise Visual
blockwise Visual    Visual    Normal              linewise Visual
linewise Visual     Visual    blockwise Visual    Normal
```